# Unexpected end of input (app.js:25) while coding

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

While coding using discord.js, there is always a syntax error at the very end of my code

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js', 'async');
const bot = new Client();
const cfg = require('./config.json');

bot.on('ready', () => {
console.log(Bot Ready on ${bot.guilds.size} servers);

bot.user.setActivity('the member list', {type: 3})

bot.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.author.bot || !msg.content.startsWith(cfg.prefix)) return;
const args = msg.content.slice(cfg.prefix.length).split(' ')
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

bot.on(guildMemberAdd, member => {
console.log('User ' + member.user.username + 'has joined the server, adding role')

var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'New Member')

member.addRole(role)

console.log(`Args: ${args}\nCommand: ${command}`)
});

bot.login(cfg.token);
```

This is supposed to grant a newly joined member a New Member role, though whenever the code is run, this error is thrown

```
C:\Users\Sparxo\Desktop\AutoRole\app.js:25
});
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is clearly an error with my closing syntax, as there's always an error after bot.login(cfg.token). Any help?

Comment: This means you have mismatched brackets. Tell your editor to indent the code, you'll probably see the problem.

Comment: You're missing the matching `})` for `bot.on('message'` and `bot.on('ready'`.

Answer (score 0):

You've never closed the `ready` event, with `});`. Make sure to do this always, or get a linter to check your code for you!

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic, and should be flagged and closed, not answered

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm new to stack overflow, my apologies